# ASP.NET C# How to retrieve data from SQL Server and convert multi-row data into one row seperated by comma?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this table in SQL Server:

```
Colors
-----------
Grey
Black
Pink.Red
```

I wish to retrieve data from SQL Server and display in a label.

Expected output:

```
Grey,Black,Pink.Red
```

The code I have tried:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Colors FROM ROCK", con);
cmd.Connection.Open();
pdl.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); // assign to label
cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8?

Comment: 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `STRING_AGG` (this works only from `SQL Server 2017` onwards)

```
SELECT STRING_AGG (Colors, ',') AS csv FROM ROCK;
```

Or you can using `STUFF` & `XML PATH`

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + Colors FROM ROCK FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: I get the error 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: what is the sql server version you are using?

Comment: I query from ASP.net, I'm using sql server 2016

Comment: @ShiJieTio, try with XML PATH

Answer (score 0):

STRING_AGG function is not available in sql server 2016. It is available in higher version of sql server.
To achieve your task you can use **LINQ** and **sting join** function of **C#**.

For example take all row of sql data into a DataTable dt.

```
var res = string.Join(",", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x =>x["Colors"]));
```

Or you can use COALESCE function of sql server like this

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + Colors 
FROM ROCK
SELECT @listStr
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code in your .cs page

```
string color="";
for (int i = 0; i < Colors.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Colors.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                color += Colors.Items[i].Text + ",";
            }
        }
        color = color.TrimEnd(',');
        pd1.text=color;
```